# Java Language----"file.java.swp" instead of "file.java", resulting javac to be not recognized?

Tags: java

I am using the Java language and trying to program for a simple single line of text.

I turned on DOS and got to make a file (with a "vi thing" I downloaded with Cygwin) like this:

```
C:\folder>vi Howdy.java
```

I press enter and a blank space appears and I type EXACTLY like in the tutorial video:

```
apublic class Howdy {
       public static void main(String Arg[]) {
              System.out.println("Howdy Y'all!);
      }
}
```

Then compile the program. I turned on another DOS, and got it to display my files and directories. In the tutorial video, the instructor's file appeared correctly as "Howdy.java", but mine appeared as "Howdy.java.swp".

When I tried to use javac with it, DOS told me javac was not recognized as an internal or external command.

I am very perplexed and deeply troubled! I've been trying to troubleshoot it all day long but couldn't get it. If anyone would shed some light at all, I would be tearfully thankful.

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but that's not what DOS is. DOS is (was) an operating system. You're using the command line / command prompt / terminal. Also, you poor thing: you're just learning Java and are trying to learn vi at the same time?! Use a [normal editor](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) for sake of your sanity.

Comment: Also note that `System.out.println("Howdy Y'all!);` should be `System.out.println("Howdy Y'all!");` (unmatched quotes)

Comment: And `apublic class` should be `public class`

Comment: I typed "a" infront of "public class" because when I tried typing "public class", it showed "E535 Register not found"......I don't understand that. It wouldn't work until I typed "a" or "i". @Monster Truck

Comment: @Boann I don't really understand what a vi editor is...The instructor of the course "expecting no programming experience" was using vi, so I copied him. I don't know how to use anything else. :-S

Comment: @JeanWeng Vi is an abstruse labyrinth designed to make typing more complicated than it should be. It's so complicated it's tricked you into thinking you "don't know how to use anything else" when you do, because you're typing on this web page just fine. You can use just Notepad to edit Java files. Or get something like Notepad++ for more power and useful syntax highlighting (it colors programming words depending on their meaning). Once you're done learning the principles of running programs on the command line ("DOS"), get Eclipse or NetBeans, which are more sophisticated but more friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't have the Java compiler(`javac`) in your `PATH`.

Find your Java JDK install directory (it's usually `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0` or something similar).  Then, follow these [instructions](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) on how to set your `PATH`.  Make sure you put the `bin` directory on the path (it's the one with the Java executable files, like `java` and `javac`).  Once you're done with that, close any open command prompts and re-open them.

That .swp file is the vim temp file that is created when you have the file open.  You should have the non .swp file in the same directory.  Try removing the .swp part when you compile.  It's there for file integrity purposes.  You can ignore it for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where javac is installed and run it. Seems you did not set JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: I did set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

Comment: can you try going to this folder and running javac from there?